# Create duplicate copies of value in same shape as another tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor of some arbitrary shape. I want to create a second tensor of the same shape but populated with some value `c` so I can multiply them together pairwise. I currently have the following code. `input` is the tensor with a predetermined shape and arbitrary values.

```
input_size = tf.size(inputs)
mult = [c]*input_size
mult = tf.reshape(mult, shape = inputs.shape)
tf.reduce_prod([inputs, mult], axis = 0, keep_dims = True)
```

There's two problems with this current code. Firstly, mult is not initially created as a tensor and I can't just state shape = inputs.shape. I'm new to tensorflow so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`tf.constant`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/constant_op/constant_value_tensors#constant) or [`tf.fill`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/constant_op/constant_value_tensors#fill) to create a constant tensor of specified shape:

```
tf.constant(c, shape=inputs.shape)
```

or:

```
tf.fill(inputs.shape, c)
```

---

*Examples:*

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
...     print(sess.run(tf.constant(3, shape=[3,3])))
... 
[[3 3 3]
 [3 3 3]
 [3 3 3]]
>>> with tf.Session() as sess:
...     print(sess.run(tf.fill([3,3], 3)))
... 
[[3 3 3]
 [3 3 3]
 [3 3 3]]
```

Comment: What if c is a tensor instead of a constant? How can I duplicate the value in the tensor to create the desired shape. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: How do you want to duplicate the value? Can you give an example of the `inputs` and `c`? And what you'd like `mult` to be? You might need `tf.stack`.

Comment: This is the tensor for c: Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) and the tensor for input is Tensor("unit_1_0:..", shape=(?, 16), dtype=float32). I would like the tensor for mult to be the same shape as c except with the value for stored in the tensor for c.

Comment: `c` has nothing in it. What do you expect for it to be multiplied with another tensor?

Comment: c should have one element. I want to multiple all elements of inputs by 1/c but maybe there's an easier way to what I'm doing.

Comment: Have you tried `inputs/c`? This should work if `c` is a scalar and have the same `dtype` as `inputs` due to *broadcasting*.

Comment: oh no, I haven't. I'll try that now.